# Problem SQLServerDriver server name contains comma

Tags: java, sql-server, odbc-sql-server-driver

I am trying to connect a SQL server and for this I am using the driver provided by microsoft
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Now they changed the connection by adding a comma to it and I can no longer create the connection, does anyone know how to make the drive take the literal connection? Or for these cases I have to make a special configuration.

The server name is:
**200.100.100.17,6058**

The same so far I can connect from Sql Server Management Studio but not from java, I have the connection String like this

**jdbc:sqlserver://200.100.100.17,6058;databaseName=FinancialPortfolio**

Comment: `200.100.100.17,50748` is not server name, it is server ip address and port

Comment: Try `200.100.100.17:6058` instead.  JDBC wants a `:` for port number

Comment: 6058 is not a port, is part of server name

Comment: @IsraelGonzalez No, that's an IP address / port combination.  It's not a server name.  It can be entered in the servername parameter, but it's not a server name.

Comment: I would actually find the host name and use that

Comment: but, my string connection add 
dbc:sqlserver://200.100.100.17:6058;databaseName=FinancialPortfolio
and not working, 
¿is my string connection wrong?

Comment: Assuming that missing the `j` at the start is a typo in  your comment, what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, java jdbc:sqlserver://200.100.100.17:6058;databaseName=FinancialPortfolio

Comment: That's *not* the exact error message ;) A paraphrase is not going to help. What is the hostname?